# Eclipse Oxygen with JBoss tools startup takes a while

Tags: eclipse, jboss-tools

Does anybody have a fix or workaround for this problem? My Eclipse oxygen with JBoss tools takes too long to load/startup. I have tried upgrading JBoss tools  and then increased `-Xmx` in `eclipse.ini` but it still is slow to load. Looking at `/workspace/.metadata/.log` I found this:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.ide 2 17 2019-07-24 12:20:57.786
!MESSAGE Server ‘org.jboss.tools’ failed with exception: redhat.ctrlflow.com. ; version: 2.0.7.v20170906-1327
!STACK 0
java.net.UnknownHostException: redhat.ctrlflow.com
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:111)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
at org.apache.http.client.fluent.Request.internalExecute(Request.java:173)
at org.apache.http.client.fluent.Executor.execute(Executor.java:262)
at org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ide.server.mars.IO.request(IO.java:170)
at org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ide.server.mars.IO.refreshConfiguration(IO.java:64)
at org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ide.server.mars.ServerConnection.startUp(ServerConnection.java:124)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractIdleService$DelegateService$1.run(AbstractIdleService.java:62)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Callables$4.run(Callables.java:122)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.ide 2 17 2019-07-24 12:21:07.587
!MESSAGE Server ‘org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.ide.server’ failed with exception: Read timed out. ; version: 2.0.7.v20170906-1327
!STACK 0
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:282)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:167)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
at org.apache.http.client.fluent.Request.internalExecute(Request.java:173)
at org.apache.http.client.fluent.Executor.execute(Executor.java:262)
at org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ide.server.mars.IO.request(IO.java:170)
at org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ide.server.mars.IO.refreshConfiguration(IO.java:64)
at org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ide.server.mars.ServerConnection.startUp(ServerConnection.java:124)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractIdleService$DelegateService$1.run(AbstractIdleService.java:62)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Callables$4.run(Callables.java:122)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

It's trying to connect to `redhat.ctrlflow.com`. I tried browsing to this URL but it is unreachable. Removing JBoss tools is not an option. Hoping someone can shed some light on this matter. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix, go to Windows > Preferences > General > Startup and Shutdown. Uncheck **Eclipse Automated Error Reporting** and any plugin that starts with **JBoss Tools**. Apply and Close. Restart and then the `MESSAGE Server ‘org.jboss.tools’ failed with exception...` and `MESSAGE Server ‘org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.ide.server’ failed with exception...` will no longer appear in `/workspace/.metadata/.log`.

Answer (score 0):

AERI service has been shutdown so you may disable the error reporting but I'm not sure this is the source of slow startup

Comment: Hmmm disabling error reporting seems to work. Window -> Preferences -> General -> Error Reporting -> Configure Projects. Still showing the same errors in the log but it's faster.